# WebView Xamarin OnPermissionRequest

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have found the following Java code which I am trying to convert to C# for use in a Xamarin Android project

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        // Need to accept permissions to use the camera
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            L.d("onPermissionRequest");
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });
```

what would this translate to in C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not support inner-classes like Java does. You can created a nested `WebChromeClient` subclass within the class you are working with:

```
public class CustomChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
    {
        request.Grant(request.GetResources());
    }
}
```

And then:

```
webView.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomChromeClient());
```

Re: [Nested Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)

Comment: @G-Man no problem 